# Fid the coefficient of thermal expansion of liquid

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, space-expansion, fluid-statics

[image]
Please explain why we get two different expansion for two different methods i.e. when we equate the pressure at Aand D ,and at C and B and which is correct and why because in book and at other platforms the pressure of C and B is equated which gives different answer unlike A and D...

Comment: FIrst, avoid screenshots and type the text properly (especially with low-quality screenshots like this one...) Second, give more details about your computation to pinpoint exactly what your question is about. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if the diagram of the apparatus was shown.